# json undefined when not parsed, and unexpected token when parsed

Tags: javascript, php, json, postgresql

Having issues getting my json response back from an SQL query in javascript

This is my javascript

```
  setNouvelle: function(id, action){
        this
    .$http
    .get('news.api.php?function=getNouvelle&id='+id)
    .then(function(response){
      if (action == 'modal') {
        this.modal.nouvelle = response.data;
      } else if(action == 'edit') {
        this.nouvelle = response.data;
        this.nouvelle.publication = 
        moment(this.nouvelle.publication).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      }
    });
},
```

On the PHP side I have an postgresql query that uses json_build_object and then I send it with

echo json_encode($nouvelle);

When launching the action setNouvelle, the response.data contains the following :

```
"{"id" : 1872, "title" : "Test Title", "publication" : "2017-09-05T00:00:00", "summary" : "This is a test summary ", "category" : "admin", "content" : "<h2 style=\"text-align: justify;\">This is the test content ", "relateddisciplines" : [{"id" : 2, "name" : "Men's", "code" : "men"}, {"id" : 3, "name" : "Women's", "code" : "wen"}], "athlete" : [{"id" : 37359, "firstname" : "Reb", "lastname" : "ANDRADE", "federation" : "POR"}, {"id" : 25224, "firstname" : "Paul", "lastname" : "BULA", "federation" : "FRA"}], "events" : [{"id" : 15191, "startevent" : "2017-09-01", "endevent" : "2017-09-03", "title" : "World Cup", "city" : {"name" : "Minsk", "country" : {"code" : "BLR"}}, "status" : "approved", "hasresults" : true, "disciplines" : [{"code" : "men"}, {"code" : "wen"}]}], "keywords" : [{"id" : 40, "value" : "Women's"}, {"id" : 49, "value" : "Men's"}, {"id" : 347, "value" : "World Cup"}, {"id" : 771, "value" : "Minsk"}]}"
```

However I cannot use individual parts of the returned data, for example, showing the summary with this.nouvelle.summary

If I try JSON.parse(response.data), I get the following error message :

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

How can I set this up so that I can use individual attributes of the JSON response

Thanks

Edit :

this is my app declaration :

```
var app = new Vue({
http: { options: { emulateJSON: true, emulateHTTP: true }},
el: '#app',
data: {
nouvelle: {
  id : "",
  title: "",
  summary: "",
  content: "",
  category: "",
  publication: "",
  press_release: "",
  keywords: [],
  athletes: [],
  events: [],
  relateddisciplines: [],
  create_time: ""
 },
 nouvelles: [],
 modal: {
  nouvelle: {
    id : "",
    title: "",
    summary: "",
    content: "",
    category: "",
    publication: "",
    press_release: "",
    keywords: [],
    athletes: [],
    events: [],
    relateddisciplines: [],
    create_time: ""
}},
file: {},
addMode: true,
alert: {
  cls: "hidden",
  message: "",
  time: 0
}
```

Comment: which Javascript library are you using ?

Comment: thats not valid json [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I'm using Vue.js

Comment: The error message using your validator is :                                        
Error: Parse error on line 1:
"{"id " : 1872, "title
---^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

Comment: @wzirmer yes it's because of the quotation marks at start and end

Comment: It's already an object, just do `response.data.id`  etc

Comment: Ok thanks, I copied the json from chrome developer tools so I'm not sure if the javascript uses the quotations or not.

Comment: response.data.id comes back as undefined

Comment: `response.id`  `response.title`  etc..  the point is it's already an object, that's what the o is in the error, the first letter of object

Comment: Tried response.title, response.body.nouvelle.title and response.data.nouvelle.title, all return undefined

Comment: Try to `console.log(response)`. If there is a `data` property - refer to it.

Comment: the data property contains the nouvelle object, but I cannot use it

Answer (score 1):

Made it work by changing this line :

```
this.modal.nouvelle = response.data;
```

to

```
this.modal.nouvelle = JSON.parse(response.body.nouvelle);
```

Wasn't parsing the right thing